# XPath - extracting text between two nodes

Tags: xpath

I'm encountering a problem with my XPath query. I have to parse a div which is divided to unknown number of "sections". Each of these is separated by h5 with a section name. The list of possible section titles is known and each of them can occur only once. Additionally, each section can contain some br tags. So, let's say I want to extract the text under "SecondHeader".

HTML

```
<div class="some-class">
 <h5>FirstHeader</h5>
  text1
 <h5>SecondHeader</h5>
  text2a<br>
  text2b
 <h5>ThirdHeader</h5>
  text3a<br>
  text3b<br>
  text3c<br>
 <h5>FourthHeader</h5>
  text4
</div>
```

Expected result (for SecondSection)

```
['text2a', 'text2b']
```

Query #1

```
//text()[following-sibling::h5/text()='ThirdHeader']
```

Result #1

```
['text1', 'text2a', 'text2b']
```

It's obviously bit too much, so I've decided to restrict the result to the content between selected header and the header before.

Query #2

```
//text()[following-sibling::h5/text()='ThirdHeader' and preceding-sibling::h5/text()='SecondHeader']
```

Result #2

```
['text2a', 'text2b']
```

Yielded results meet the expectations. However, this can't be used - I don't know whether SecondHeader/ThirdHeader will exist in parsed page or not. It is needed to use only one section title in a query.

Query #3

```
//text()[following-sibling::h5/text()='ThirdHeader' and not[preceding-sibling::h5/text()='ThirdHeader']]
```

Result #3

```
[]
```

Could you please tell me what am I doing wrong? I've tested it in Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just test the first preceding sibling `h5`...

```
//text()[preceding-sibling::h5[1][normalize-space()='SecondHeader']]
```

Comment: Could you please answer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73096265/xpath-to-use-preceding-and-following-sibling-in-a-single-statement?noredirect=1#comment129100801_73096265)

Answer (score 2):

If all `h5` elements and text nodes are siblings, and you need to group by section, a possible option is simply to select text nodes by count of `h5` that come before.

Example using `lxml` (in Python)

```
>>> import lxml.html
>>> s = '''
... <div class="some-class">
...  <h5>FirstHeader</h5>
...   text1
...  <h5>SecondHeader</h5>
...   text2a<br>
...   text2b
...  <h5>ThirdHeader</h5>
...   text3a<br>
...   text3b<br>
...   text3c<br>
...  <h5>FourthHeader</h5>
...   text4
... </div>'''
>>> doc = lxml.html.fromstring(s)
>>> doc.xpath("//text()[count(preceding-sibling::h5)=$count]", count=1)
['\n  text1\n ']
>>> doc.xpath("//text()[count(preceding-sibling::h5)=$count]", count=2)
['\n  text2a', '\n  text2b\n ']
>>> doc.xpath("//text()[count(preceding-sibling::h5)=$count]", count=3)
['\n  text3a', '\n  text3b', '\n  text3c', '\n ']
>>> doc.xpath("//text()[count(preceding-sibling::h5)=$count]", count=4)
['\n  text4\n']
>>>
```