# How to extract lines between repetitive n number of tags from XML and continue until last tag?

Tags: python, xmllint

I have an XML file with over 2,500 `<Item>` elements.

The example below shows the sample layout. I want to copy every line in between `<Item name="1st">` and the `<Item name="500th">` to a new file as is. Then continue to the next 500 from `<Item name=501st">` onwards, and write that out to a new file. Result is 5 new files. Nothing to be skipped.

```
<Item name="1st"><ItemProperties>
<property>data</property><property>data</property>
</ItemProperties>
...
...
<Item name="500th"><ItemProperties>
<property>data</property><property>data</property>
</ItemProperties>
```

The below operation does it for the first 500, but I do not know how to keep going until the last closing tag.

```
xmllint --xpath "//Item[position()<=500]" FileName.XML > Output1.XML
```

See [this link](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/a7c2dbf132f9edd018d1ad3f33972b21) for an example:

Comment: So the result is five files of the five parts?

Comment: Is there exactly one tag on each line?

Comment: There are could be multiple tags in each line. I am interested to copy every line from 1st <Item> tag to 500th </Item> close tag. As is.

Comment: Are you trying to figure out a way to extract lines from some starting position through some ending position? Check out this other question for some information on how to use "following-sibling" and "preceding-sibling" in xpath: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35613785/xpath-extracting-text-between-two-nodes

Comment: following-sibling and preceding-sibling will jump over some important data. My intention is to copy lines as is to a new file. Is there a way to have xpath recognize the last position it stands before creating a new file and then start from that position?

Comment: If you want to post the real xml file somewhere, it will be easier to provide an answer.

Comment: Posted salparadise

Comment: @K4rt does my second solution get what you need?

Comment: I am testing it now, I will let you know. Thanks for checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using python, first solution is to treat from line 0 to the last line, one line at a time:

```py
nfh = None
with open('foo.xml') as fh:
    num = 0
    for index, line in enumerate(fh):
        if not index % 500:
            num += 1
            if nfh:
                nfh.close()
            nfh =  open('file_name{}.txt'.format(num), 'w')
        nfh.write(line)
if nfh:
    nfh.close()
```

Second, is using lxml to enumerate only specific tag in the XML file:

```py
import lxml.etree as etree
xml_data = etree.parse('foo.xml')
nfh = None
num = 0

for index, tag in enumerate(xml_data.xpath('//Item')):
    # Enumerate 500 tags
    if not index % 500:
        num += 1
        if nfh:
            nfh.close()
        nfh =  open('Output{}.XML'.format(num), 'wb')
    nfh.write(etree.tostring(tag))
if nfh:
    nfh.close()
```

This, assuming your XML is closer to this:

```xml
<root>
<Item name="1st"><ItemProperties>
<property>data</property><property>data</property>
</ItemProperties>
</Item>
<Item name="2nd"><ItemProperties>
<property>data</property><property>data</property>
</ItemProperties>
</Item>
....
<Item name="500th"><ItemProperties>
<property>data</property><property>data</property>
</ItemProperties>
</Item>
....
</root>
```

Comment: Once I declared value for num after nfh, it did the job for the requested question. Thank you.

Comment: Also, my original file contains  more than 2000 Item tags while the parsed outputs does not equal to enough number of Item tags. Would you know why?

Comment: @Kr4t Do you want every tag or just the "Item" tags?

Comment: I want to copy every line in between <Item></Item> including the mentioned tags. Lxml solution does it but for some reason it is not accurate. The original file, when I search has 2800 <Item> tags. However, output files altogether contain only less than 1200-1300 <Item> tags. This is the most updated version of the code https://pastebin.com/t5iPwdAr

Comment: @K4rt How are you getting the 2800 number?

Comment: I do basic search on Notepad++ for <Item and it gives me that number. But when I do exact same search for individual files generated from the pycode, it only gives me half that number.

Comment: @K4rt I can only speculate since I don't have the source file. Can you post the source file somewhere?

Comment: Unfortunately it would be impossible without a lot of effort to clean the data. What is your speculation? What are some possible causes? Tags in the example are identical to original file.

Comment: Screenshot from the original xml file here [link](https://ufile.io/enonh)

Comment: Sorry, that screenshot is more confusing than helpful, I don't see the 'Item' tag (is it 'ReportItem'?) and I can't see what is under it. perhaps `Item` is a field somewhere else or even yet you are counting the closing tags, hence how close it is to 1/2 the number.

Comment: Yes, Item tag in the original report is equivalent to ReportHost. Everything in between is necessary to be copied to a new file. When I search, I search for the opening tag as <ReportHost and it gives me 2000+ number.

Comment: You are right. I did search using find /c and it found only as many as the pycode generated. I also looked up using xmllint count and it also generated the same numbers. Upvote for keeping it up with this. Thanks again.

Comment: You've got it salparadise!

Answer (score 0):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xml_doc = ET.parse('table.xml')
results = xml_doc.getroot()
def chunkify(lst,n):
  # Split the list into 'n' equal parts
  return [ lst[i::n] for i in xrange(n) ]

count = 1
for f in chunkify(results,5):
  temp_str = ''
  for element in f:
    temp_str = temp_str + ET.tostring(element)
  with open(str(count) +"_Output.xml", "w") as text_file:
    text_file.write(temp_str)
  count = count +1
```

Comment: Hi Himanshu dua, thanks for the response. Can you please add few lines of comment to your pycode? How does your pycode recognize which tag I am trying to start from and where to end?

Comment: Himanshu, could you please read the question again? The XML file I am dealing with has other data before and after <Item> tags. I am only interested to copy lines in between 1st and nth <Item>, then copy from the last </Item> to the next nth <Item> until I reach the end of the file. Your pycode in contrary will chunkify any given xml into ~ 5 equal parts. Am I right?