# XPATH to use preceding and following sibling in a single statement

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, xpath, lxml

I would like to scrape name, address informations between  tag contains defendent text and another  tag,

My HTML structure is:

```
<hr>
<H5>Defendant/Respondent Information</H5>
<span class="InfoChargeStatement">(Each Defendant/Respondent is displayed below)</span>
<table>
<tr>
<td><span class="FirstColumnPrompt">Party Type:</span></td><td><span class="Value">Defendant</span><span class="Prompt">Party No.:</span><span class="Value">1</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr>
<td><span class="FirstColumnPrompt">Name:</span></td><td><span class="Value">Name 1</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr>
<td><span class="FirstColumnPrompt">Address:</span></td><td><span class="Value">Addr 1</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span class="FirstColumnPrompt">City:</span></td><td><span class="Value">city1</span><span class="Prompt">State:</span><span class="Value">aa</span><span class="Prompt">Zip Code:</span><span class="Value">Zip1</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
<hr>
<table>
<tr>
<td><span class="FirstColumnPrompt">Party Type:</span></td><td><span class="Value">Defendant</span><span class="Prompt">Party No.:</span><span class="Value">2</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr>
<td><span class="FirstColumnPrompt">Name:</span></td><td><span class="Value">Name 2</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr>
<td><span class="FirstColumnPrompt">Address:</span></td><td><span class="Value">Addr2</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span class="FirstColumnPrompt">City:</span></td><td><span class="Value">City2</span><span class="Prompt">State:</span><span class="Value">st2</span><span class="Prompt">Zip Code:</span><span class="Value">zip2</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
<hr>
<H5>Related Persons Information</H5>
<span class="InfoChargeStatement">(Each Related person is displayed below)</span>
<table>
<tr>
<td><span class="FirstColumnPrompt">Name:</span></td><td><span class="Value">Unwanted Name</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr>
<td><span class="FirstColumnPrompt">Address:</span></td><td><span class="Value">un addr</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span class="FirstColumnPrompt">City:</span></td><td><span class="Value">Unwanted City</span><span class="Prompt">State:</span><span class="Value">Unwanted city</span><span class="Prompt">Zip Code:</span><span class="Value">12345</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table></table>
<hr>
```

My current XPATH capturing the first occurence of Name and address properly, but if need to extract the multiple occurences, it also scrape the information from the unwanted h5 tags.

My current XPATH is,

`"//*[contains(text(),'Defendant')]//following-sibling::table//span[text()='Name:' or text()='Business or Organization Name:']/ancestor-or-self::td/following-sibling::td//text()")`

I tried including preceding sibling and following sibling but nothing gives my expected output,

My current output is..

```
names - [
Name1,
Name2
Unwanted Name,
]
```

Expected output is,

```
[
Name1
Name2

]
```

Kindly help.

Comment: Try sibling::table[1]

Comment: I dont know how many names will be there, in this case its 2 for defendent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
"//H5[contains(text(),'Defendant')]/following-sibling::table[not(preceding-sibling::H5[not(contains(text(),'Defendant'))])]/tr[td[1][span[text()[.='Name:' ]]]]/td[2]/span/text()"
```

It first selects the table that has `not` a `preceding-sibling::h5` with `text()` that `not` `contains` `'Defendant'` and than
selects from the correct table the `tr` where the first `td` meets your requirements and selects the second `td`

No need for double slashes which is bad for performance

**EDIT 1**

Since there are more preceding-sibling::h5 than the example shows, this `XPath` will deal with that:

```
"//H5[contains(text(),'Defendant')]/following-sibling::table[preceding-sibling::H5[1][contains(text(),'Defendant')]]//tr[td[1][span[text()[.='Name:' ]]]]/td[2]/span/text()"
```

This will only select those tables that have as there first preceding-sibling::h5 the same h5 as we were interested in

**EDIT 2**

Actually now the first `h5` select is redundant. This `XPath` will do:

```
"//table[preceding-sibling::H5[1][contains(text(),'Defendant')]]//tr[td[1][span[text()[.='Name:' ]]]]/td[2]/span/text()"
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, ill test it out, but actually the ending h5 tag text can be anything, in our case it is `Related Persons Information` but it can be anything, can we modify the xpath accordingly pls

Comment: actually your initial solution was matching and the newer solution `H5[not(contains(text(), 'Defendant'))]` not matching the tag

Comment: Strange. In my editor it works. Do you have a link to the real source?

Comment: Edited the answer after testing it on the actual html-page

Comment: Hi @siebe can we change the exact match `Name` to contains??

Comment: Sure. Give it a go.  Let me now if you need more help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246726/discussion-between-pyd-and-siebe-jongebloed).